# Filter Child Property OData and ASPNET WebApi

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm facing a problem. I've googled a lot and searched in here too, but I couldn't find a answer to this problem.

I have a `ASPNET Web Api` that returns `JSON`. I also, add [Microsoft.Data.OData](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.OData/) nuget to allow odata queries.

It's working fine for simple cases, but now, I need to apply a filter in a child collection.

Sample:

```
{"total":1,"products":[{"id":20289,"brandId":5,"categoryId":1,"price":12.0,"name":"Carolina Herrera","description":"CH","productCode":"asd2334","picture":null,"contentPackaging":"liquid","brandName":"Carolina Herrera","brandPicture":null,"generic":true},
{"id":20290,"brandId":5,"categoryId":1,"price":25.0,"name":"Carolina Herrera 2","description":"CH 2","productCode":"asd999","picture":null,"contentPackaging":"liquid","brandName":"Carolina Herrera","brandPicture":null,"generic":true}
]}
```

I want to query in products collection where price is greater than 20 for example.

I've tried something like this:

```
http://domain.com/api/$filter=products/price gt 20
```

But that didn't work.

Is it possible to do that?

Code:

```
//controller
public IQueryable<ViewModelProducts> GetProducts()
{
    var products = _repository.FindBy(x=>x.Generic && x.Status).ToList();

    return products.Count == 0 ? new List<ViewModelProducts>().AsQueryable() : products.AsQueryable();
}

//model
public class ViewModelProducts
{
    public int total { get; set; }
    public IQueryable<Products> products { get; set; }
}

public class Products
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int brandId { get; set; }
    public int categoryId { get; set; }
    public decimal price { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string productCode { get; set; }
    public string picture { get; set; }
    public string contentPackaging { get; set; }
    public string brandName { get; set; }
    public string brandPicture { get; set; }
    public bool generic { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The query looks fine... what error are you seeing?

Comment: @Roysvork is not filtering my products array. It's displaying exactly the same json. Ps: I'm tenting through RESTClient (firefox addon)

Comment: I'm assuming the typo in the word 'products' is just present here in the question and not in your code too?

Comment: Also, please post the code from your controller\action so we can see what is going on server side.

Comment: @Roysvork actually it exists in my model. I'll post code in here

Comment: Cool ta, one more q... do you have the [Queryable] attribute on your controller action?

Comment: @Roysvork No, I'm not using this attribute